# understanding given header file

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I got task from my university class in computer science, to build a binary search tree, according to a given header file.
but, i don't quite understand the function in it, it's a mix of pointers and structers.

this is the header file:

```
#ifndef GENBST_H
#define GENBST_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef void* Elm;
typedef void* BST;
typedef void* BST_ROOT;
typedef enum {SUCEESS, OUT_OF_MEM, BAD_ARGS, FAILURE } Result;
BST_ROOT BSTCreate( Elm root_val, Elm (*create_elm)(),
    void (*cpy_elm) (Elm,Elm),
    int (*cmp_elm) (Elm, Elm),
    void (*free_elm)(Elm) );
void BSTDestroy (BST_ROOT root);
Result BSTAddElement (BST_ROOT root, Elm node);
Result BSTRemoveElement (BST_ROOT root, Elm node);
Elm BSTFindElement (BST_ROOT root, Elm node);
#endif
```

Can you help me figure out what every function means? 
Specific in BSTCreate function?

Comment: you cannot know what a header file does if you don't have any documentation or source code. The only thing you can know is what you have here: function names, typedefs, and eventually some structures declarations. 

I think your task is to code the .c which implements the functions which can be found in this .h. It's your job to make the functions that are declared here.

Comment: sure, I need to build the c file to realize the function in the header, my problem is that i don't understand what is written in the functions..

Comment: If an answer solved your problem or helped you, please consider to accept it, see also:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot give a full answer to this but I hope that this explanation will help you.

First of all, as said in the comments by Magix, there are no function definition in a header file, however, the header files gives you the specification on how the interface should be. it specify the functions prototypes and the types of variables, given these,  you should be able to implement the BST.

Try to write down an algorithm and see if you can implement it by using all the prototypes declared in this header.
Said that, it would be of great help to have also two lines of explanation ;)

Let's take a look of each piece of the header!
First of all you are given elements in the Tree and the type of BST:

```
typedef void* Elm;
typedef void* BST;
typedef void* BST_ROOT;
```

Then the enum specify the values of some return type that you can use:

```
typedef enum {
 SUCCESS,           // 0 (I corrected the spell)
 OUT_OF_MEM,        // 1
 BAD_ARGS,          // 2
 FAILURE            // 3
} Result;
```

Here you understand that you must provide a function that create a BST.

```
BST_ROOT BSTCreate( 
    Elm root_val, 
    Elm  (*create_elm)(),
    void (*cpy_elm) (Elm,Elm),
    int  (*cmp_elm) (Elm, Elm),
    void (*free_elm)(Elm) );
```

This function must use the four other functions:

```
    Elm  (*create_elm)(),
    void (*cpy_elm) (Elm,Elm),
    int  (*cmp_elm) (Elm, Elm),
    void (*free_elm)(Elm)
```

Finally you should also provide a set of functions to modify the BST:

```
void BSTDestroy (BST_ROOT root);
Result BSTAddElement (BST_ROOT root, Elm node);
Result BSTRemoveElement (BST_ROOT root, Elm node);
Elm BSTFindElement (BST_ROOT root, Elm node);
```

Comment: Thank you for cuting it to pieces :)

Answer (score 0):

It is some sort of semi-failed attempt at type-generic programming and the creation of an ADT ("abstract data type"). "Semi-failed" because there's too generous use of void pointers and no type safety. In particular, it is very bad practice to hide pointers behind typedef. Anyway...

`Elm` probably refers to "element", that is the actual data to store in the tree. The `root_val` would then obviously be top top value of the tree.

The rest of the parameters are function pointers. It is a template of sorts: the functions must have the specified formats.

Apparently you are meant to supply pointers to data-specific functions for every tree you create. For each specific data type, these functions can then be implemented in a suitable way. You could have one set of functions for `int`, one set of functions for strings etc etc. And create one kind of tree for each such data type.

`create_elm` and `free_elm` are pointers to functions for creating/deleting an element of the specific type (compare with constructor/destructor in C++).

`cpy_elm` is likely supposed to be a function copying the specific elements (compare with overloaded assignment operator in C++).

And `cmp_elm` is the actual comparison function, likely supposed to return -1, 0 or 1 depending on if param1 is less than, equal, or greater than param2. Look at how to use the C standard `bsearch` function and the meaning of this function will become clearer. There are plenty of examples on SO.

Comment: Thank you, my first step to understand it.
now, what is the meaning of this?

        ' Elm  (*create_elm)() ' 

with my understanding, I need to create pointer to function "create_elm, that is Elm type,but how can i sent different type of data to a single function?

Comment: @ohad You make a custom function with same signature as that function pointer, for example something like. `Elm create_string (void) { return calloc(1, 10); }`. And then you pass a pointer to `create_string` as the `create_elm` parameter. Your function call will end up looking something like (string example): `BST_ROOT bst_string = BSTCreate("hello world", create_string, copy_string, cmp_string, free);` where the first parameter is some dummy value I made up, and the rest are functions matching the listed function pointers.